# Há alguma maneira de executar um programa java (.jar) a partir de um programa C ou C++?

Tags: java, c, c++

Eu quero saber se há uma maneira de eu escrever um programa `.jar`, e escrever um programa C/C++ que chamasse o JVM para executar o arquivo `.jar`. É possível? Se sim, podem me dar um exemplo de código ou uma instrução de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solução mais padrão seria utilizando a função `system()` da biblioteca padrão `stdlib.h`.

**PORÉM**, do ponto de vista de sistemas `*nix`, o uso de `system()` deve ser evitado:

> **1** - A chamada da função `system()` executa o interpretador de comandos
>   (shell), o que o torna muito mais lento que a chamada de um `fork()`
>   seguido de um `exec()`;
>
> **2** - É um potencial risco de segurança se você passar como parametro
>   uma string de fonte não confiável;
>
> **3** - Não pode ser usado de maneira assíncrona, ou seja, o sistema fica
>   bloqueado aguardando o retorno do processo filho;
>
> **4** - A dupla `fork()` e `exec()` nos dá um controle muito maior antes e entre as suas
>   chamadas.

O programa a seguir exemplifica execução de um `.jar` utilizando as chamadas de `fork()`, `exec()` e `waitpid()` em um sistema `Linux`.

Repare que o processo filho, antes de fazer a chamada de `exec()`, prepara o ambiente redirecionando os fluxos de saída (`STDERR` e `STDOUT`) para dois arquivos de saida: `stderr.txt` e `stdout.txt`.

O fluxo do processo pai é bloqueado de propósito com a chamada de `waitpid()`, mas poderia estar "trabalhando" em outra tarefa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MAX_CMD_TAM  (1024)

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char cmd[ MAX_CMD_TAM + 1 ] = {0};

    /* Verifica se o nome de arquivo .jar foi passado como parametro na linha de comando */
    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Erro de sintaxe: %s [ARQUIVO_JAR]\n", argv[0] );
        return 1;
    }

    /* Processo pai cria uma copia de si mesmo (cria um processo filho) */
    pid_t child = fork();

    /* Monta a linha de comando que sera executada */
    snprintf( cmd, MAX_CMD_TAM, "java -jar %s", argv[1] );

    if( child == 0 ) /* Fluxo do processo filho */
    {
        /* Abre/Cria arquivos para substituirem as saidss padroes: STDOUT e STDERR */
        int fdout = open( "stdout.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );
        int fderr = open( "stderr.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );

        /* Redireciona o STDOUT e STDERR para os arquivos correspondentes */
        dup2( fdout, STDOUT_FILENO );
        dup2( fderr, STDERR_FILENO );

        /* Depois de duplicados, os descritores dos arquivos nao sao mais necessarios */
        close(fdout);
        close(fderr);

        /* Executa comando */
        execlp( cmd, NULL );
    }
    else if( child > 0 ) /* Fluxo do processo pai */
    {
        /* Processo pai aguarda a execucao do processo filho */
        printf( "Executando Comando: \"%s\"\n", cmd );

        printf( "Aguardando a execucao do processo filho...\n");
        waitpid(child);

        printf("Sucesso!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("fork() falhou!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 10):

Pode usar a linha de comando ([`system()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system)):

```
 java -jar "arquivo.jar"
```

Dependendo do que quer fazer pode usar [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). É bem complicado.

Comment: Dependendo do caso tem a [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) também.

Comment: Obrigado. Já encontrei a resposta em uma pergunta similar.