# Chamar comando cd em c++ usando system()

Tags: c++, shell

Estou tentando "programar um shell" dentro do C++ mas não estou conseguindo usar o comando cd (caminho) ele simplesmente não vai, pesquisei e vi que quando uso o `system()` é criado uma nova shell fora do diretório em que estamos sendo assim não consigo utiliza-lo, qual seria a solução?

PS: Os outros comandos (pelo que testei) pegam normalmente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LIMITE 256

int main (void){
char comando[LIMITE];


//Laço
while(1){
    printf("teste@teste-VirtualBox:~$ ");
    if(fgets(comando, sizeof(comando), stdin) != NULL){
        system(comando);
    }
}


return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você está fazendo um shell, melhor que chamar 'system' é chamar 'fork' e 'execvp' em Linux or 'CreateProcess' em Windows. Alguns exemplos para Linux são dados em inglês por outros que também estão fazendo um shell:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675094/minishell-problems-with-cd-c

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049898/implement-linux-shell-in-c

Chamando 'system' criará um novo processo que usa um shell para processar o comando dado. Se der 'cd' como comando, o novo processo mudará seu próprio caminho e terminará, deixando o caminho de seu programa o mesmo que antes.

O comando 'cd' não é um programa que se chama, então terá que fazer seu shell reconhecer e processar o comando 'cd' por se mesmo. Para implementar este comando, pode chamar 'chdir' para mudar o caminho.

Comment: Também tem um exemplo de como usar 'fork' e 'exec' em português aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142384/h%C3%A1-alguma-maneira-de-executar-um-programa-java-jar-a-partir-de-um-programa-c/142509#142509

Comment: As respostas do Lacobus são ótimas =]

Answer (score 3):

voce pode usar o chdir para forçar essa mudança de diretorio para o system no linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
   //apontamos o terminal para /
   chdir("/");
   system("pwd");

   //apontamos o terminal para /home/kodonokami
   chdir("/home/kodonokami");
   system("pwd");
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no windows podemos ter o mesmo resultado com SetCurrentDirectory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void){
   //apontamos o terminal para c:\
   SetCurrentDiretory("c:\\");
   system("dir");

   //apontamos o terminal para c:\windows
   SetCurrentDiretory("c:\\windows");
   system("dir");
}
```

se colocar os comandos no mesmo system separados por ponto e virgula tambem funciona (no windows é usado o & para separar), voce pode usar o cd sempre quando chamar o system passar para ele uma variavel que tem o diretorio atual e modificar essa variavel quando precisar mudar o diretorio

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
   //isso é uma gambiarra '-'
   system("cd / ; pwd ; cd /home/kodonokami ; pwd");
}
```

outra forma pode ser feito executando a shell pelo programa como ja foi citado pelo Kyale A

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
    execv("/bin/sh",NULL);
}
```

tem outras formas alem das citadas ^^